# Retrieve log of a pipeline without azure analytics

Tags: logging, azure-data-factory

I Need to automate the check status on various pipeline without connect to monitor and without log analytics.
Do you known if exist another way?
With python, Is It possibile read directly the Log of pipeline without log analytics?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API can directly read the Log of pipeline with python. But you can use this code to get status of pipeline run.

```
pipeline_run = adf_client.pipeline_runs.get(rg_name, df_name, run_response.run_id)
```

Ref:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.activityrun?view=azure-python

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-python#monitor-a-pipeline-run